# MySQLi: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, mysqli

guys. 
I have been few days trying to access MariaDB from php script, but I have not succeeded.This is the code (I copied it from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_mysql_connect.asp))

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";

//Se crea la coneccion con la Base de Datos
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password);
//Se asegura que todo este correcto
function conectar(){
    if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    die ("Coneccion a Base de Datos fallida: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}?>
```

When I try to execute it, this is the result:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so'- /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_connect in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/lisa.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
 thrown in /var/www/html/lisa.php on line 7
```

Comment: is the library installed?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/784629/php-mysqli-so-undefined-symbol-mysqlnd-connect-in-unknown-on-line-0

Comment: Yes. /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so

Comment: That doesn't look like a normal PHP installation directory. How did you install PHP? The date directory component is **old**, and I don't think `mysqlnd` exists with that name anymore. It got merged into the main development code around PHP 5.3 (which is itself **super old** and definitely shouldn't be used in 2019). See https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Ok, it work!!.Thank you so much!!.

Comment: Yeah, well ... first I compile it (php 7), but it gave me a lot of problems and I deleted it completely (or so I thought). Then I reinstall it with "sudo apt-get install php7.0". And that this all.

Comment: Even PHP 7.0 is so old it's no longer supported, and PHP 7.1 will only get security updates until December, 2019. I _**strongly**_ urge you to use PHP 7.3 if you're starting a new project.